# Wordpress website uploads texts before images

Tags: wordpress, elementor

My website uploads texts some fraction of a second before the images or graphic appears.
I use elementor pro as my website builder and hello theme. Please wish to know how to tackle this issue. Thanks for helping.

Comment: html file loads faster than images. This is it nothing else.
Could also be image lazy load.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: your browser prioritizes smaller file sizes. Use properly optimized images and make sure to use the webm format for optimal user experience.

That's it. There's nothing more to it than that. Use smaller images. You can look through google's do's and don'ts [here](https://web.dev/learn/).